# Simple LED FPGA Circuit

Tags: fpga, intel-fpga, quartus

I am new to digital design, and have recently purchased a Bemicro MAX10 FPGA development board to help get my feet wet. I am trying to learn VHDL, and have downloaded a few PDFs to get me started. The circuit I am trying to create is a simple LED circuit. There are two buttons that are inputs, and two LEDs that are the outputs. The idea is that, when either button_0 or button_1 is pressed on the board, LED_1 lights up. When both buttons are pressed, both LEDs light up. Here is the code I have written to accomplish this:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.ALL;

entity Button_LEDs is
    Port ( button_0 : in std_logic;
           button_1 : in std_logic;
           LED_0 : out std_logic;
           LED_1 : out std_logic);
end Button_LEDs;

architecture Behavorial of Button_LEDs is 

begin
    LED_0 <= (button_0 AND button_1);
    LED_1 <= (button_0 OR button_1);    
end Behavorial;
```

The issue is that when either button_0 or button_1 is pressed, LED_0 lights up instead of LED_1. The line

```
LED_0 <= (button_0 AND button_1);
```

is behaving like an OR gate rather than and AND gate.
Both LEDs light up when both buttons are pressed, which is expected. I have double checked pin assignments, and I am positive that they have been assigned correctly, so I am very confused by this logic.

Comment: I can't think of any way this can happen except if a) you somehow still mixed up the pin assignments despite having double-checked, or b) the silkscreen on the pcb has swapped the labels between the LEDs.

Comment: @ThePhoton Or the switches and LEDs are both active-low?

Answer (score 1):

Alex, my advice is:

1. double double check identifiers of bottons and LEDs.
2. Use **combinational** logic if you have no specific requirements of **behavior** modeling. If you do want to have a behavior-modeling procedure, make sure that default electrical level is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Something important to remember is that sometimes FPGA development boards (buttons, LEDs, etc) are active-low. Meaning, the buttons are at '1' when they are unpressed, and '0' when they are pressed.

The LEDs in this FPGA seem to be active-low as well (so they switch on when they are assigned '0'). This is my conclusion from looking at the [schematic](https://static5.arrow.com/pdfs/2014/11/26/1/24/3/371/arrowd_/manual/bemicro_max_10-schematic_a4-20141008.pdf?_ga=1.126851981.1692452798.1461773333) for this FPGA.

So, when your buttons are not pressed:
LED_0 <= '1' AND '1'
LED_0 is '1' (so it's off).

Whenever one of the buttons is pressed it will go to '0' and then LED_0 will switch on, making it seem like an OR. To solve this, you should write:

```
LED_0 <= button_0 OR button_1;
```

What about LED_1? It seems that in this situation it should act like an AND gate.

Comment: I don't think the FPGA is active-low. The FPGA is whatever you program it to be. The switches/LEDs might have been wired up on the dev kit to be such though.

Comment: OK. Maybe a more accurate way to write what I meant is that the **development board** is active-low. I will edit my answer.